# How to implement a subscriptable class in Python (subscriptable class, not subscriptable object)?

Tags: python

To implement a subscriptable object is easy, just implement `__getitem__` in this object's class definition.
But now I want to implement a subscriptable class. For example, I want to implement this code:

```
class Fruit(object):
    Apple = 0
    Pear = 1
    Banana = 2
    #________________________________ 
    #/ Some other definitions,         \
    #\ make class 'Fruit' subscriptable. /
    # -------------------------------- 
    #        \   ^__^
    #         \  (oo)\_______
    #            (__)\       )\/\
    #                ||----w |
    #                ||     ||

print Fruit['Apple'], Fruit['Banana']
#Output: 0 2
```

I know `getattr` can do the same thing, but I feel subscript accessing is more elegant.

Comment: I have no answer for you, but I would like to know why? To me it looks like a regular Hash:

    >>> Fruit = {'Banana': 0, 'Apple': 1}
    >>> print Fruit['Banana']
    0

Comment: @Pengman I also want to implement 'Fruit' as a enum type. `if sth == Fruit.Apple: doSomething()`.

Comment: Also, it seems to me that your real problem may require Python equivalent of "enums" and "constants" - tehre are several solutions for this in Python - check Pypi for "enum" - this one seems to be a favorite: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/flufl.enum/3.3.2

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Seems to work by changing the metaclass. For Python 2:

```
class GetAttr(type):
    def __getitem__(cls, x):
        return getattr(cls, x)

class Fruit(object):
    __metaclass__ = GetAttr

    Apple = 0
    Pear = 1
    Banana = 2

print Fruit['Apple'], Fruit['Banana']
# output: 0 2
```

---

On Python 3, you should use [Enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) directly:

```
import enum

class Fruit(enum.Enum):
    Apple = 0
    Pear = 1
    Banana = 2

print(Fruit['Apple'], Fruit['Banana'])
# Output: Fruit.Apple, Fruit.Banana
print(Fruit['Apple'].value, Fruit['Banana'].value)
# Output: 0 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me add some explanation: Class is also object in Python. The type of 'class object' is define by `__metaclass__`, default to `type`. So if you need a subscriptable class, just implement `__getitem__` in its `__metaclass__`. For more information about `__metaclass__`, read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: @AbhiP Try the [webarchive version](http://web.archive.org/web/20140424195834/http://mikewatkins.ca/2008/11/29/python-2-and-3-metaclasses/), or [this useful link](http://www.pythoncentral.io/how-metaclasses-work-technically-in-python-2-and-3/) which shows the same code for both python 2 and 3 metaclasses.  Looks like Mike Watkins has temporarily taken down his article.

Answer (score 59):

Add something like this to your class:

```
class Fruit(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.Fruits = {"Apple": 0, "Pear": 1, "Banana": 2}
     def __getitem__(self, item):
         return self.Fruits[item]
```

Answer (score 9):

Expanding on [@LuisKleinwort's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35995074/13710015), if you want to do  this for all class attributes:

```py
fruits_dict = {'apple':0, 'banana':1}

class Fruits(object):
    def __init__(self, args):
        for k in args:
            setattr(self, k, args[k])
            
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return getattr(self, item)

fruits = Fruits(fruits_dict)
print(fruits.apple)
print(fruits['apple'])
```

Answer (score 9):

I do think you were asking about subscripting to a class not an instance of a class.

Here is my answer to the question: "How to create a subscriptable class in Python?"

```
class Subscriptable:
    def __class_getitem__(cls, item):
        return cls._get_child_dict()[item]

    @classmethod
    def _get_child_dict(cls):
        return {k: v for k, v in cls.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith('_')}


class Fruits(Subscriptable):
    Apple = 0
    Pear = 1
    Banana = 2
```

---

```
>>> Fruits['Apple']
    0
>>> Fruits['Pear']
    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `self.__dict__.update(kwargs)` & `getattr(self, item)`.

```
class TrainingArgs:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return getattr(self, item)
```

Test:

```
>>> args = TrainingArgs(learning_rate=1e-4, batch_size=8, epochs=10)
>>> args['learning_rate']
0.0001
>>> args['batch_size']
8
>>> args.epochs
10
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way:
in your example, the definition of the class `Fruit` is what makes an object of the class `Fruit` subscriptable
So to make the class on itself subscriptable you need to define it in the class definition that defines the class object, so in essence, the class of the class
And a class of a class is a metaclass (which itself is just a class that inherits from `type`), giving you the final code like this:

```
class FruitsMeta(type):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.__dict__[item]

class Fruits(metaclass=FruitsMeta):
    Apple = 0
    Pear = 1
    Banana = 0

print(Fruits["Pear"]) # outputs 1
```